# How do I change the name of the database in Apache OpenMeetings 2.1.0?

Tags: apache, conferencing, openmeetings

How do I change the name of the database in **Apache OpenMeetings 2.1.0**?

Which parts of the **persistence.xml** do I change, or do I have to edit some other files too?

I want to change the name of the mysql database from '**openmeetings**' to something else, maybe '**db_openmeetings**'.

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the connection properties:

See: mysql://localhost:3306/openmeetings

localhost = host
3306 = port
openmeetings = name of database

```
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionProperties"
                value="DriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                    , Url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openmeetings?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;cachePrepStmts=true&amp;cacheCallableStatements=true&amp;cacheServerConfiguration=true&amp;useLocalSessionState=true&amp;elideSetAutoCommits=true&amp;alwaysSendSetIsolation=false&amp;enableQueryTimeouts=false&amp;prepStmtCacheSize=3000&amp;prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=1000
                    , MaxActive=100
                    , MaxWait=10000
                    , TestOnBorrow=true
                    , poolPreparedStatements=true
                    , Username=root
                    , Password=" />
```